# How come this maze solver works?

Tags: javascript

How come the maze solver below works ? To me it looks like as soon as it hits anything other than a 1 or a 2 it should stop. How is it possible that it keeps going when it hits a 0?

```
var myMaze = [
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
  [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
];

function MazeSolver(maze) {
  this.maze = maze;

  this.traverse = function (column, row) {
    if (this.maze[column][row] == 2) {
      console.log("We solved the maze at (" + column + ", " + row + ")");
    } else if (this.maze[column][row] == 1) {
      console.log("At valid position (" + column + ", " + row + ")");
      this.maze[column][row] = 9;
      if (column < this.maze.length - 1) {
        this.traverse(column + 1, row);
      }
      if (row < this.maze[column].length - 1) {
        this.traverse(column, row + 1);
      }
      if (column > 0) {
        this.traverse(column - 1, row);
      }
      if (row > 0) {
        this.traverse(column, row - 1);
      }
    }
  };
}

var ms = new MazeSolver(myMaze);
ms.traverse(3, 0);
```

Comment: This concept is called [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#In_computer_science); the main function has an inner function (`this.traverse`) which keeps calling itself until it finds the exit. It basically uses the [floodfill algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill#The_algorithm) to replace zeros with nines spreading into all directions until it hits the 2.

Comment: It's the classic recursive maze solving approach, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_solving_algorithm#Recursive_algorithm, an application of depth-first search, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search

Comment: In a sense it does stop when it hits a `0`, however "it" in this case is a single instance of the function being called, and as mentioned above the function is called recursively. So when one instance finishes, its parent continues execution.

Comment: @ChrisG once it enters the traverse method and the current position is a 0,  where does it call itself again ? wouldnt that require another if statement where this.maze[column][row] == 0

Comment: When it encounters `0`, it simply returns, and the next `if` tries going to a different direction.

Comment: Sorry, the algorithm replaces *ones* with nines, as far as I can tell (I initially thought that ones are walls, but they are the paths). Also, as tevemadar has said, each iteration explores all four directions, simply moving to the next one if there's no 1.

Comment: @ChrisG I thought the current execution would stop on every recursive call to this.traverse(). But I see now that it keeps going and tries each of the four directions. Thank you :)

Comment: The current execution *does* kind of stop, but not before kicking off the next four executions, that's why it keeps going.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered in the comments (recursion) but as mazes can have multiple solutions for completeness I am providing modified version which will log every solution from the shortest to the longest and pretty print path and number of steps taken.

```js
var myMaze = [
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
  [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
  [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
  [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2],
  [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
]

function MazeSolver(maze) {
  this.maze = maze
  this.solutions = []

  this.traverse = function (column, row, maze) {
    const path = maze.map((arr) => arr.slice())
    if (path[column][row] == 2) {
      this.solutions.push(path)
    } else if (path[column][row] == 1) {
      path[column][row] = 8
      if (column < path.length - 1) {
        this.traverse(column + 1, row, path)
      }
      if (row < path[column].length - 1) {
        this.traverse(column, row + 1, path)
      }
      if (column > 0) {
        this.traverse(column - 1, row, path)
      }
      if (row > 0) {
        this.traverse(column, row - 1, path)
      }
    }
  }

  this.solve = function (column, row, maze) {
    this.traverse(column, row, maze)
    const solutions = this.solutions
      .map((solution) => [
        solution.reduce(
          (acc, cur) => acc + cur.filter((e) => e === 8).length,
          0
        ),
        solution,
      ])
      .sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0])
      solutions.unshift([0, maze])
    solutions.forEach((sol) => {
      container.innerHTML += !!sol[0] ? (sol[0] + " steps:") : "problem:"
      container.innerHTML += "<br>"
      sol[1][column][row] = "S"
      sol[1].forEach((row) => {
        container.innerHTML += row.map(e => {
        if (e === 0) return "."
        if (e === 8) return "+"
        if (e === 1) return " "
        if (e === 2) return "F"
        return e
        })
        .join(" ")
        container.innerHTML += "<br>"
      })
    })
  }
}

var ms = new MazeSolver(myMaze)
ms.solve(3, 0, myMaze)
```

```css
div {
font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```